# Trying to parse the using json parse method but unable to do so

Tags: json, node.js

```
include('extras/json2.js');
var top = JSON.parse(topology.txt);
```

The `topology.txt` is in the same folder so no path errors.

Error shows: `ReferenceError: "topology" is not defined`.

Comment: Try put `var filename = 'topology.txt'; var top = JSON.parse(filename);`

Comment: Test you JSON in `topology.txt` file with this validator: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You did not load your file. Load it using `require` as such:

```
var top = require('topology.txt')
```

Node.js should parse JSON by default.